# The call back assigned to my Compler.future object is not being called when I complete the completer after a network call

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm new Dart and have an iOS background so I might be using the language incorrectly which is leading to my code not working as expected but I also cannot find a solution online and thought I would ask it here incase someone else has experienced it and fixed it.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is have a model factory create a datasource in which you pass the request type (GET or POST), pass in an endpoint, and some params. Then it will return you back a future in which you listen for a `then()` call, this is called when the network request is successful/fails. The code I currently have works up until the point when I call completion.complete(responseObject);...nothing happens after that.

Code for the few functions that are involved:

Inside the Model Factory:

```dart
BaseDataSource bds = new BaseDataSource();
Map params = {"api_key": "random","session_id": "random", "account_id": "random"};
Future<Map> request = bds.makeRequest(NetworkingRequestType.GET, params, "music/songs");
request.then((Map responseObject) {

});
```

Inside the Datasource:

```dart
enum NetworkingRequestType {
   GET, POST
}

class BaseDataSource {

  static final String baseServerURL = config[appRunMode]["baseServerURL"];

  Future<Map> makeRequest(NetworkingRequestType type, Map params, String endpoint) {
    Future<Map> completion;

    switch (type) {
      case NetworkingRequestType.GET:
        completion = _makeGetRequest(endpoint, params);
        break;

      case NetworkingRequestType.POST:
        break;
    }

    return completion;
  }

  Future<Map> _makeGetRequest(String endpoint, Map params) {
    final uri = new Uri(path: "${baseServerURL}${endpoint}",
    queryParameters: params);
    return HttpRequest.getString("${uri}").then(JSON.decode);
  }
}
```

Comment: You return `completion.future`, but `completion` is a `Future`, not a `Completer`?

Comment: That was a mistake I made when editing the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't spot anything wrong with this code, except that it does not propagate errors. It should work. If `completion.complete` is invoked then `completion.future` must complete, check that `completion.complete` is indeed invoked (e.g. check if there were any network errors on the console, check Network tab in DevTools to see request/response).

In general though I'd recommend avoiding explicit usage of completers. Just use the future returned by `then` instead of `completer.future`:

```dart
  Future<Map> makeRequest(NetworkingRequestType type, Map params, String endpoint) {
    switch (type) {
      case NetworkingRequestType.GET:
        return _makeGetRequest(endpoint, params);

      case NetworkingRequestType.POST:
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<Map> _makeGetRequest(String endpoint, Map params) {
    final uri = new Uri(path: "${baseServerURL}${endpoint}",
                        queryParameters: params);
    return HttpRequest.getString("${uri}").then(JSON.decode);
  }
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for commenting so quickly. Also thanks for the Uri tip, it's a much cleaner way to do that.

But as far as my code working, it's not. Not sure why though. The Future from the .then(JSON.decode) is returned and I attach a then() to it once back in the Model Factory but no dice. So in theory the then() execution should be HTTP Request Return String->JSON.decode parses it->I handle making the models, if everything worked that is. I do see the HTTP request returning a 200 ok from my server.

Comment: @ApperleyA this is weird. I tested the code and it works http://dartlab.org/#9d14391454bf11f96e01 [the bottom-right frame takes a while to load because it compiles to JS right in the browser]. Also as @lrn pointed above in your version of the code you need to return `completion` not `completion.future`. You'll get `NoSuchMethod` error on that line.

Comment: I got it to work...not sure how but it started working today. Thanks for looking at my code and the help you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to me like some mixture of using `Completer` and not using `Completer`.

How the code would look like when using `Completer`:

```dart
Future<Map> makeRequest(NetworkingRequestType type, Map params, String endpoint) {
    // Future<Map> completion; // <= if you want to use a completer this should be
    Completer<Map> completion = new Completer<Map>()

    switch (type) {
      case NetworkingRequestType.GET:
        // completion = _makeGetRequest(endpoint, params); // <= this would change to
        _makeGetRequest(endpoint, params).then((result) => completion.complete(result));

        break;

      case NetworkingRequestType.POST:
        // completion.complete({});
        _makePostRequest(endpoint, params).then((result) => completion.complete(result));
        break;
    }

    return completion.future;
  }
```

but you probably don't need to use a `Completer` for this use case.

The code would then look like without using `Completer`:

```dart
Future<Map> makeRequest(NetworkingRequestType type, Map params, String endpoint) {

    switch (type) {
      case NetworkingRequestType.GET:
        return _makeGetRequest(endpoint, params);

        break;

      case NetworkingRequestType.POST:
        // return new Future.value({}); // or whatever you want to do here 
        return _makePostRequest(endpoint, params);
        break;
    }
  }
```

caution: code not tested.